# 'if' in ext.xtemplate for inexistent JSON object

Tags: extjs3

My JSON has most of the time these two in its structure: "type" and "comments". Sometimes it has instead "type", "survey", "comments". So, I'd like to use "if" to let ext.xtemplate showing the ones it finds. For instance I've tried this but doesn't work:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div style="text-align:justify;text-justify:inner-word">',
    '<b>Type:</b> {type}<br/>',
    '<tpl if="survey">',
        <b>Survey:</b> {survey}<br/>',
    '</tpl>',
    '<b>Comments:</b> {comments}',
    '</div>'
```

I've tried instead these ones too but with no success:

```
<tpl if="survey != {}">
<tpl if="survey != undefined">
```

how could be the right way to detect an inexistent object?, thanks in advance.

PS. I'm using ExtJS 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `values` local variable, for example:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div style="text-align:justify;text-justify:inner-word">',
    '<b>Type:</b> {type}<br/>',
    '<tpl if="values.survey">',
        '<b>Survey:</b> {values.survey}<br/>',
    '</tpl>',
    '<b>Comments:</b> {values.comments}',
    '</div>'
);
```

Besides `values` there are also other variables available, which are helpful in some cases: `parent`, `xindex`, `xcount`.

Template after preprocesing is executed as a function, your template look like this:

```
function (values, parent, xindex, xcount){ // here are values, parent, etc
    with(values){ // each property of values will be visible as local variable
        return [
            '<div style="text-align:justify;text-justify:inner-word"><b>Type:</b> ',
            (values['type'] === undefined ? '' : values['type']),
            '<br/>',
            this.applySubTemplate(0, values, parent, xindex, xcount), // each <tpl> is converted into subtemplate
            '<b>Comments:</b> ',
            (values.comments === undefined ? '' : values.comments),
            ''
        ].join('');
    }
}
```

This knowledge usually helps with understanding XTemplates.

Example usage of mentioned variables: http://jsfiddle.net/gSHhA/

Answer (score 0):

I use `<tpl if="!!survey>"`

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, but anyway you should explain why it should.

Comment: I use the !! to force a javascript variable to boolean, so non empty "string", non zero number are evaluated as true. Where empty string, 0, null and undefined are false. 

I typically use it like this:
<tpl if="!!contactname">
    Contact name: {contactname}
</tpl>

this saves me having to do multiple checks, on empty string and existence of the property